# Autowire not work in telegram app using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, telegram-bot, long-polling

I make my telegram bot using java library [TelegramBots](https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots) and also use SpringBoot in my application.

When in class **TelegramBotPolling** there is called method **onUpdateReceived** than the field **busStationBtnsGenerator** is null.

How corectly autowire field **busStationBtnsGenerator** in order it will be not null when **onUpdateReceived** method is called ?

This is brief example of my code:

```
@Component
public class TelegramBotPolling extends TelegramLongPollingBot {

    @Autowired
    BusStationBtnsGenerator busStationBtnsGenerator;

    static {
        ApiContextInitializer.init();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void registerBot(){

         TelegramBotsApi telegramBotsApi = new TelegramBotsApi();
         try {
           telegramBotsApi.registerBot(new TelegramBotPolling());
         } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
           logger.error(e);
    }
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {   
      // When this method is called field "busStationBtnsGenerator" is  null. 
    }   
}



@Component
public class BusStationBtnsGeneratorImpl implements BusStationBtnsGenerator {

   @Autowired
   BusStationsParser stationsParser;

   @Autowired
   UrlHelper urlHelper;


   @Override
   public InlineKeyboardMarkup getKeyboardMarkupForBusStations() 
   throws Exception 
   {
       ......
   }

  private List<List<InlineKeyboardButton>> getBusStationButtons() 
  throws Exception 
  {
      .....
  }

}
```

Comment: pls paste BusStationBtnsGenerator  class

Comment: is TelegramBotPolling class a spring bean?

Comment: @Kick, I added **BusStationBtnsGenerator ** class in my question.

Comment: @pvpkiran, no **TelegramBotPolling** is not spring bean class. It is third party library that I use to connect to my telegram bot.

Comment: No any annotation on TelegramBotPolling  class, add Component on it

Comment: @Kick, sorry **TelegramBotPolling** has **Component** annotation. I forgot to add this annotation when wrote my question. I fixed my question.

Comment: It should work, please retest it

Comment: @Kick, I tested another time, but It didn't work. I found the exact reason of problem. Main problem is different context. Variable **busStationBtnsGenerator**.in method **registerBot** not null, because **registerBot** in spring context. But method **onUpdateReceived** from third party library not use spring context. And that why **busStationBtnsGenerator** is null. At this time I don't know how to include spring context in third party method **onUpdateReceived**?

Comment: How do you create an instance of TelegramBotPolling class?

Comment: @AndriySlobodyanyk, actually I don't use **TelegramBotPolling** directly. I simply extend abstract **TelegramLongPollingBot** class and implement some abstract methods (**onUpdateReceived** is one of this abstract method). And all other works do for me third party library [telegramBots](https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots).

Comment: @foxis, well, do you register your bot at the library API? Or does the library find necessary classes itself?

Comment: @AndriySlobodyanyk, yes, this work do exactly method **registerBot**.

Comment: @foxis, do you call method registerBot? Show the code, please?

Comment: @AndriySlobodyanyk, I added code to method **registerBot**. Actually I don't call **registerBot** explicitly, because this method has annotation PostConstruct, so Spring call it itself during initializations of beans.

Comment: @foxis, Well, root cause is founded. I've added the answer.

Comment: @AndriySlobodyanyk, sorry the field **busStationBtnsGeneratorInstance** actually not use in program. I forgot to delete the row **busStationBtnsGeneratorInstance = busStationBtnsGenerator;** (I use it for some experiments). Now I delete this row in my example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154658/discussion-between-andriy-slobodyanyk-and-foxis).

Comment: @AndriySlobodyanyk, ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instance of class created with constructor **new** is not managed by Spring. For referring it you should you **this** keyword in this case.

```
@PostConstruct
public void registerBot(){
     TelegramBotsApi telegramBotsApi = new TelegramBotsApi();
     try {
       telegramBotsApi.registerBot(this);
     } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
       logger.error(e);
}
```